# Code doesn't allow the user to input letters

Tags: java

So far I have a code that asks for a user input but a part of my code isn't accepting letters as inputs. For example if i type in say woah123 it'll give me a number format exception. Any way to get around this? Error is at the second line int i = Integer.parseInt(sentence).
Sentence is the user input

```
sentence.replaceAll("\\D", "");
int i = Integer.parseInt(sentence);
i = i * 2 ;
woah.replaceAll("\\d", "" + i);
System.out.println(woah);
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. It should be `sentence = sentence.replaceAll("\\D", "");`

Comment: @ZouZou post it as an answer

Comment: @ZouZou Same thing for `woah`.

Comment: Same question i came through on "SO" yesterday . what is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Strings are immutable.

Generally, every modification you made on an immutable object will "give" you another immutable object.

So it should be :

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Indeed you have to do the same for `woah`.

You may read about what is an [immutable object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

Comment: Assuming that OP may be new to Java/programming [immutable object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) means that each method you invoke on this object will not change its sate (will not affect it), optionally it will give you new object of same type with changed state. In this case since String is immutable `replaceAll` will give you new String object with changed characters but will not affect original one, so if you want to update `sentence` reference you will need to assign result of `replaceAll` to this reference like ZouZou shown in his answer.